# 307 redirect, Set-Cookie, not working in IE 11 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

Ran into an odd issue here which I am struggling to find a solution for. I am posting form data to a third party address, getting the response, then adding the Location and Set-Cookie headers to my own page. This is working fine in chrome, the third party finds the cookie as required. IE 11 not so great... Looking in fiddler the differences I can see are that Chrome takes the cookie with it on it's journey to the third party page and IE does not.

```
        //Get the response handle
        var webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();

        //Add reponse headers and status code
        Response.StatusCode = 307; // redirect
        Response.Headers.Add("Location", "https://THIRD_PARTY_DOMAIN" + webResp.Headers["Location"]);
        Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", webResp.Headers["Set-Cookie"]);

        // workarounds found online with no joy
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-cache");

        //Dispose of objects
        webResp.Close();
        webResp.Dispose();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-T

Comment: Does the url have an underscore in it?

Comment: No, there are no underscores in the redirect URL

Comment: Is there one in any of the urls?

Comment: No none of the URL's have underscores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I ended up looping through the headers collection in then web response and appending these to my Response.Headers where appropriate. This and a clear of the browser(s) cache seemed to resolve the issue.